# How can obtain energy of a signal using stockwell´s transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

The stockwell´s transform is defined as: $$S(t,f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)w(t-τ,f)e^{-2\pi if\tau}d\tau$$ Where $$w(t-τ,f)$$ is the gaussian window.
I need obtain the energy of a signal using the representation time-frequency given by this transform. And do not know if I can obtain the energy as in the fourier transform with windows (STFT) where: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty|STFT(t,f)|^2 dtdf = \int_{-\infty}^\infty|x(t)|^2 dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty|X(f)|^2 df = E_x$$

Comment: If you really need the STFT and other filter-bank transforms, then start by reading a course on the Fourier series and the discrete Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

start from the [spectral definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_transform#Modified_Form) of the Stockwell transform:
$$ S(t,f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f+\alpha)e^{-\pi\alpha^2/f^2}e^{2\pi i\alpha t}d\alpha$$
integrate over time to obtain the Fourier transform of the signal,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty S(t,f)dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f+\alpha)e^{-\pi\alpha^2/f^2}\delta(\alpha)d\alpha=X(f)$$
then integrate over frequency to obtain the energy in the signal,
$$E_x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty S(t,f)dt\right|^2 \,df\qquad[1]$$

so this is different from what is written in the OP, the integral over time should be *before* taking the absolute value squared, not after,
$$E_x\neq\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty |S(t,f)|^2 \,dt df\qquad[2]$$
the difference is also obvious from dimensional analysis: $S$ has dimensions of $X$ times frequency, while energy has dimensions of $X^2$ times frequency, as in equation [1], while equation [2] has dimensions of $X^2$ times frequency *squared*, which is mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I knew that variant that you show me, but if I take $$S(t,f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)w(t-τ,f)e^{-2\pi ift}d\tau$$ as the fourier transform of $$y(τ,f) = x(t)w(t-τ,f)$$ that is $$ Y(f) = S(t,f) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)w(t-τ,f)e^{-2\pi ift}d\tau$$ and then using parseval's theorem to say: $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |Y(f)|^2df = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |y(τ,f)|^2dτ$$ and from there, to follow the development and check the result. Would it be wrong to do so?

Comment: what you write is correct if you replace $x(t)$ by $x(\tau)$ and $e^{-2\pi ift}$ by $e^{-2\pi if\tau}$; not sure how this would answer your question, however, your equation for $E_x$ is definitely mistaken.

Comment: You're right, let me show you my idea. if I take $$S(t,f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)w(t-τ,f)e^{-2\pi if\tau}d\tau$$ as the fourier transform of $$y(τ,f)=x(τ)w(t-τ,f)$$ that is $$Y(f) = S(t,f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)w(t-τ,f)e^{-2\pi if\tau}d\tau$$ and then using parseval's theorem to say: $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |Y(f)|^2df =\int_{-\infty}^\infty |y(τ,f)|^2dτ$$. Then:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty |S(t,f)|^2dtdf = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(τ)w(t-τ,f)|^2dτdf =\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(τ)|^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty|w(t-τ,f)|^2dfdτ$$ is my idea right?

Comment: Interesting where can one go to learn about Signal Analysis but targeted for Mathematicians ?